# How to use XmlReader to read a short tag XML without adding a closing element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-2.0

My XML looks something like this (read it from file):

```
<root>
  <date month="November" year="2001"/>
</root>
```

I'm trying to edit the year attribute value in the date element, let's say to be "3000".
I'm using XmlDocument and XmlReader classes in order to edit this attribute, like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();            
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath))
      xml.Load(reader);
```

The problem is, that the XmlReader reads the XML like this:

```
<root>
      <date month="November" year="2001"> </date>
</root>
```

Meaning, it adds the closing element to the date element.
I'm saving the edited XML later with the Save method.

I need the final XML to be with short tags like the original XML.
Is there a way to use the XmlReader without adding the closing element?

Comment: If you are only reading, then you can use `reader.IsEmptyElement` to check that; but fundamentally they mean the same thing

Comment: I'm reading, editing and saving.
I know they mean the same thing, but i need the edited XML to be with empty element like the original.

Answer (score 3):

If the XML file is not very big you could use an [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) to edit it in-place:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
var date = xml.Element("date");
date.Attribute("year").SetValue("3000");
xml.Save("test.xml");
```

Comment: Is it available in .Net 2.0 ?

Comment: @Tom No, it was added in .NET 3.5 as part of the LINQ Framework. If there is a specific .NET Runtime you have to target then it would be worth adding that as a tag against your question.

Comment: I added it, for some reason it was removed.
I added it again

Answer (score 0):

Try this solve your problem. i simply update year attribute, you can change accordingly

```
    XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Book.xml"));
        XmlNode node;
        node = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode node1 in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node1.Name == "date")
            {
                node1.Attributes["year"].Value = "2005";
            }
        }
        myXmlDocument.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Book1.xml"));
```